# map.resource and naming convention for singleton

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions, controller, routes

I am relatively new to ruby on rails, so this question might be easy. Rails does a lot of magic and I am not sure where to look up such things, because I don't know which part of the framework is to blame.

I basically did the [authlogic_example](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example) and fiddled around with the code afterwards.
My routes.rb looks like this

```
 map.root :controller => "user_session", :action => "new" # optional, this just sets the root route
 map.resources :users
 map.resource :user_session
```

As you can see, I have a controller called *user_session*. *user_session* has three actions *new*, *create* and *destroy*. I can reach the controllers at

```
 localhost:3000/user_sessions/[new,destroy,create].
```

I can also reach the new action at

```
 localhost:3000/user_session/new
```

for destroy or create I get a routing error here. According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html#M000523) the first case should be the standard one: "A singular name is given to map.resource. The default controller name is still taken from the plural name."

My problem now is that link_to only takes the singular of the controller name, where I can only reach new, but not destroy

```
<%= link_to "singular", :controller=>"user_session", :action=>"destroy" %> 
#=> http://localhost:3000/user_session/destroy
<%= link_to "plural",   :controller=>"user_sessions", :action=>"destroy" %>
#=> http://localhost:3000/user_session
```

This is pretty confusing and is not even close to what I expected, but also causes problems: I can't

```
redirect_to :controller=>"user_sessions", :action=>"destroy"
```

because I get redirected to

```
http://localhost:3000/user_session
```

As I already mentioned, I am pretty new to rails, so I might not have the right way of thinking yet. Can you point me to anything that describes this behaviour? How would I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is correct. At least for [RESTful routing.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html) Where the action to take is linked to the request type.

a POST request on http://localhost:3000/user_session will create a session. While a DELETE request on the same URI will destroy the session.

If you're mapping resources you should be using the convenience methods, to abstract most of that out.

```
<%= link_to "Login", create_user_session_url %>
```

However, map.resources doesn't provide a destroy helper. So you will either have to make one or explicitly mention :method =>  :delete

```
<%= link_to "Logout", {:controller => "user_sessions", :action => :destroy}, :method => :destroy %>
```

I prefer the named route version where this goes in config/routes.rb

```
map.logout '/logout', :controller => "sessions" , :action => :destroy
```

Then just use this in my views:

```
<%= link_to "Logout", logout_url %>
```